# Why my "before_tag" functions is not executed by "behave"

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I try to use the behave `before_tag` callback.
But is seems to be never called.

So I try to put any other before_XXX function in my environment.py file:

```
def before_all(context):
    raise ValueError("Here we are")

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    raise ValueError("Here we are")

def before_step(context, step):
    raise ValueError("Here we are")
```

But steps are still executed without exception.

As inserting invalid syntax in the same python file result in "Exception SyntaxError" it is interpreted by behave.

Do you have any idea of what can I do to identify my usage problem?
(I'm currently using behave 1.2.6)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to behave code deployed in python; I could investigate with python debuger:
environment.py shall be stored in the current directory.

I was storing it in a sub directory named steps near my other python files.
I'm now able to attach fixtures to a tag!